# Mock the return value of a mocked method in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a method that I'm trying to test and I would like to mock the methods that my method under test calls.  This mocked method calls a method which calls another method and so on.  I would like to mock the return value of the top level method, but the return value is lost.  I suspect that I am not patching in the right place, but I can't figure out where I should patch.  I've read: [Where to patch](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch), but I can't tell where I'm going wrong.

The method I'm trying to test is `get_url`, the first thing it does is create an instance of `Bar` class.  `Bar` then calls the method I want to mock, `get_obj`.  `result` should consist of a list of `objectLocation` objects, each one of which will have a url.  However the only thing I get back is a mock object with no return value.

gamma.FooClass.py

```
import BarClass

class Foo(object):

    def get_bar(self):
        bar = BarClass.Bar()
        return bar

    def resolve(self):
        bar = self.get_bar()
        result = bar.resolve()
        res = []
        for location in result.objectLocation:
            res.append(location.url)
        return res
```

gamma.BarClass.py

```
from BarLocationClass import BarLocation

class Bar(BarLocation):

    def __init__(self):
        BarLocation.__init__(self)

    def resolveResponse(self,pid):
        url = self._rest_url('resolve/%(pid)s', pid='pid')
        return self.GET(url)

    def resolve(self):
        response = self.resolveResponse('pid')
        return self._read_response(response, 1, 0,'ObjectLocationList',response_contains_303_redirect=True)
```

gamma.BarLocationClass

```
from BarRestClass import BarRest

class BarLocation(BarRest):

    def __init__(self):
        BarRest.__init__(self)

    def _rest_url(self, path_format, **args):
        url = 'www.example.com'
        return url    

    def _read_response(self, response, major, minor, d1_type_name,
                                response_contains_303_redirect=False):
        return 'fake_obj'
```

BarRestClass.py

```
class BarRest(object):

    def GET(self, url, query=None, headers=None, n_tries=3,
            dump_path=None):

        return self._send_request('GET', url, query, headers, n_tries=n_tries,dump_path=dump_path)
```

test.test_foobar.py

```
class objectLocation():
    def __init__(self):
        self.objectLocation = [Mock(url='www.example.com')]*2

class Test(unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        self.client = foo.Foo()

    @patch.object(foo.BarClass.Bar,'resolve')
    def testName(self,mock_resolve):
        mock_resolve.return_value = objectLocation()
        output = self.client.resolve()
        self.assertEqual(['www.example.com','www.example.com'],output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: There are something wrong in your code: in your test class `self.client` has not `get_url()` method because `Foo()` class doesn't have it.

Comment: I guess it is `resolve()` instead of `get_url()`

Comment: yes, I changed it to better match the code I'm testing.  I got myself in trouble trying to strip out too many details.  My apologies!

Comment: I think the best is to patch `Bar.resolve()` method and write a separate test unit to test `resolve()` behavior by patchin `GET()` that is supposed to use external resources. If it sounds good to you I'll change my answer in this way. Just an other detail: should be `url = self._rest_url('resolve/%(pid)s', pid=pid)` and not `pid='pid'`

Comment: I've edited test_foobar to try out your suggestion, but I don't get a list back after the mocked resolve method is called.  I get `result.objectLocation` = 
`<MagicMock name='resolve().objectLocation' id='140103041650960'>`.  Whereas `mock_resolve.objectLocation.return_value` = 
`[<Mock id='140103052365008'>, <Mock id='140103052365008'>]`

Comment: I 'll edit my answer. Comment is not the right place where explaining g these details.

Comment: I think I've got it now.  I created a fake class 'objectLocation' that had the properties I wanted and assigned it to the return value.  Now, when the mocked resolve method returns the a list of urls like I wanted.  I got the idea from [link](http://craiglabenz.me/2014/04/05/mocking-things-python-and-specifically-django/).  I think this is actually testing the method.  What do you think?

Comment: I think that is exactly the idea of my original answer :). Tomorrow I'll edit my answer to fit better your question and maybe I'll propose to you some solutions.

Comment: Sorry, now I cannot understand what is the question? You adopted my original answer that was designed for other code and change your question that now work. For instance you can ask if that is the right way to handle these case or not: maybe yes but you need to test also how `Bar.resolve()` fill `objectLocation`, otherwise your test is very weak... BTW: I'll remove my answer that is completely useless now!

Comment: My question was how to test the return value of the method Foo.resolve().  I have unit tests for Bar.resolve() as well.  I'm moving up the call stack from the simple methods to the more complicated.  I think your answer was very helpful.  I was totally stuck!  I think it provides a useful example to others who have complicated testing requirements.